# Global table styles

Tags: tables

Is it possible to create a global style for all tables? For example:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor,colortbl}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{hhline}
\definecolor{rowcol}{rgb}{0.7, 0.7, 0.7}

\usepackage{tabularray}

\title{Example}
\author{Anon}
\date{May 2023}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}
\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\begin{tblr}{
  colspec={X[c,m]Q[c,m]Q[c,m]Q[c,m]Q[c,m]},
  cells={font=\large},
  cell{1}{1} = {r=2}{c},
  cell{1}{1} = {c=1}{c},
  cell{1}{2} = {c=4}{c},
  hlines,
  hline{1-Z}={1}{1}{leftpos=1, rightpos=0.15},
  hline{1-Z}={1}{2}{leftpos=0.15, rightpos=1},
  hline{3}={2}{-}{solid},
  hline{3}={2}{1}{leftpos=1, rightpos=0.15},
  hline{3}={2}{2}{leftpos=0.15, rightpos=1},
  vlines,
  vline{2}={2}{-}{},
  row{odd[3]}={bg=rowcol}
}
  & Description \\
  & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
  A & 10 & 20 & 30 & 40 \\
  B & 15 & 25 & 35 & 25 \\
  C & 12 & 22 & 32 & 80 \\
\end{tblr}
\caption{Table 1}
\label{lbl1}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\begin{tblr}{
  colspec={X[c,m]Q[c,m]Q[c,m]Q[c,m]Q[c,m]},
  cells={font=\large},
  cell{1}{1} = {r=2}{c},
  cell{1}{1} = {c=1}{c},
  cell{1}{2} = {c=4}{c},
  hlines,
  hline{1-Z}={1}{1}{leftpos=1, rightpos=0.15},
  hline{1-Z}={1}{2}{leftpos=0.15, rightpos=1},
  hline{3}={2}{-}{solid},
  hline{3}={2}{1}{leftpos=1, rightpos=0.15},
  hline{3}={2}{2}{leftpos=0.15, rightpos=1}, 
  vlines,
  vline{2}={2}{-}{},
  row{odd[3]}={bg=rowcol}
}
  & Description \\
  & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
  A & 10 & 20 & 30 & 40 \\
  B & 15 & 25 & 35 & 25 \\
  C & 12 & 22 & 32 & 80 \\
\end{tblr}
\caption{Table 2}
\label{lbl2}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Here there are only two tables, but when there are many more tables having to copy these exact settings every time doesn't look pretty, and it requires many changes when you want to adjust something. Having one global style would be much better. But I couldn't find definitive answer how to do it.

Comment: Check section 3.4 "New Tabularray Environments" or also section 4.2 "Customize Templates" and following sections in the [`tabularray` manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/tabularray/tabularray.pdf).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a custom `tblr` environment as described in section 3.4 "New Tabularray Environments" of the [`tabularray` manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/tabularray/tabularray.pdf) like so (the red lines in the second table are just to show that it is always possible to override the specifications):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor, tabularray}
\definecolor{rowcol}{rgb}{0.7, 0.7, 0.7}

\begin{document}

\NewTblrEnviron{mytblr}
\SetTblrInner[mytblr]{
  colspec={X[c,m]Q[c,m]Q[c,m]Q[c,m]Q[c,m]},
  cells={font=\large},
  cell{1}{1}={r=2}{c},
  cell{1}{1}={c=1}{c},
  cell{1}{2}={c=4}{c},
  hlines,
  hline{1-Z}={1}{1}{leftpos=1, rightpos=0.15},
  hline{1-Z}={1}{2}{leftpos=0.15, rightpos=1},
  hline{3}={2}{-}{solid},
  hline{3}={2}{1}{leftpos=1, rightpos=0.15},
  hline{3}={2}{2}{leftpos=0.15, rightpos=1},
  vlines,
  vline{2}={2}{-}{},
  row{odd[3]}={bg=rowcol}
}

\section{Introduction}
\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\begin{mytblr}{}
  & Description \\
  & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
  A & 10 & 20 & 30 & 40 \\
  B & 15 & 25 & 35 & 25 \\
  C & 12 & 22 & 32 & 80 \\
\end{mytblr}
\caption{Table 1}
\label{lbl1}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\begin{mytblr}{
  hlines={red}
}
  & Description \\
  & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
  A & 10 & 20 & 30 & 40 \\
  B & 15 & 25 & 35 & 25 \\
  C & 12 & 22 & 32 & 80 \\
\end{mytblr}
\caption{Table 2}
\label{lbl2}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]